# Baby rudin prop 1.16c proof

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification

Using the field axioms, one must show that $(-x)y =-(xy)=x(-y)$. Rudin proves this one way by showing $(-x)y+xy=0$. However, how does this property not directly follow from associativity with $z = -1$?

Comment: You would first need to prove that $-x=(-1)x$, but even then, you need to be able to commute around the $-1$s.

Comment: You have to show $-x=(-1)x$

Comment: Is $-x$ not defined as shorthand for $-1x$? What is the nuance between these two?

Comment: No, it is not.  $-x$ is the (unique) real number $y$ that satisfies $x+y=y+x=0$.  Exercise:  prove that this $-x$ is the same as $(-1)x$.

Comment: I see so: $x + (-1)x=(1)x+(-1)x=x(1+-1)=x0=0$. Hence $(-1)x=-x$. Using this with the associative and commutative properties would be a valid proof for the original problem then yes?

Comment: You got it.   You can also prove it directly from the axioms using distribution laws.